# This output is piped off to an external .json file using the command line. But How do I output it on a web page?

Tags: javascript, php, json, web-crawler

This is a web_crawler that I have created with php. Nothing shows up on my web_crawler page. The program outputs the page title, descriptions, keywords and URL. This output is piped off to an external .json file using the command line. But How do I output it on a web page? Someone please help!!! T_T

ALL OF THESE CODES ARE FROM MY index.php page. No matter how much I try, the page is blank.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php

    // This is our starting point. Change this to whatever URL you want.
    $start = "http://paul.byethost31.com/";

    // Our 2 global arrays containing our links to be crawled.
    $already_crawled = array();
    $crawling = array();

    function get_details($url) {

        // The array that we pass to stream_context_create() to modify our User Agent.
        $options = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", 'headers'=>"User-Agent: howBot/0.1\n"));
        // Create the stream context.
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        // Create a new instance of PHP's DOMDocument class.
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        // Use file_get_contents() to download the page, pass the output of file_get_contents()
        // to PHP's DOMDocument class.
        @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

        // Create an array of all of the title tags.
        $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
        // There should only be one <title> on each page, so our array should have only 1 element.
        $title = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
        // Give $description and $keywords no value initially. We do this to prevent errors.
        $description = "";
        $keywords = "";
        // Create an array of all of the pages <meta> tags. There will probably be lots of these.
        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName("meta");
        // Loop through all of the <meta> tags we find.
        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++) {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            // Get the description and the keywords.
            if (strtolower($meta->getAttribute("name")) == "description")
                $description = $meta->getAttribute("content");
            if (strtolower($meta->getAttribute("name")) == "keywords")
                $keywords = $meta->getAttribute("content");

        }
        ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................
        // Return our JSON string containing the title, description, keywords and URL.
        $return '{ "Title": "'.str_replace("\n", "", $title).'", "Description": "'.str_replace("\n", "", $description).'", "Keywords": "'.str_replace("\n", "", $keywords).'", "URL": "'.$url.'"},';

        echo "<p>";
        var_dump(json_decode($return,true));
        echo "</p>";

        echo "APPLE";
    }

............................................................................
```

My question is in between the dotted lines. I tried converting the JSON into a php array. But my page is blank. Nothing aprears on my page. :( Can anyone help me fix this?

I don't know if the problem is with JSON. Because, that echo "APPLE"; is not showing up on my page either!!! :(

```
    function follow_links($url) {
        // Give our function access to our crawl arrays.
        global $already_crawled;
        global $crawling;
        // The array that we pass to stream_context_create() to modify our User Agent.
        $options = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", 'headers'=>"User-Agent: howBot/0.1\n"));
        // Create the stream context.
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        // Create a new instance of PHP's DOMDocument class.
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        // Use file_get_contents() to download the page, pass the output of file_get_contents()
        // to PHP's DOMDocument class.
        @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
        // Create an array of all of the links we find on the page.
        $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
        // Loop through all of the links we find.
        foreach ($linklist as $link) {
            $l =  $link->getAttribute("href");
            // Process all of the links we find. This is covered in part 2 and part 3 of the video series.
            if (substr($l, 0, 1) == "/" && substr($l, 0, 2) != "//") {
                $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].$l;
            } else if (substr($l, 0, 2) == "//") {
                $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"].":".$l;
            } else if (substr($l, 0, 2) == "./") {
                $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].dirname(parse_url($url)["path"]).substr($l, 1);
            } else if (substr($l, 0, 1) == "#") {
                $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"].parse_url($url)["path"].$l;
            } else if (substr($l, 0, 3) == "../") {
                $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"]."/".$l;
            } else if (substr($l, 0, 11) == "javascript:") {
                continue;
            } else if (substr($l, 0, 5) != "https" && substr($l, 0, 4) != "http") {
                $l = parse_url($url)["scheme"]."://".parse_url($url)["host"]."/".$l;
            }
            // If the link isn't already in our crawl array add it, otherwise ignore it.
            if (!in_array($l, $already_crawled)) {
                    $already_crawled[] = $l;
                    $crawling[] = $l;
                    // Output the page title, descriptions, keywords and URL. This output is
                    // piped off to an external file using the command line.
                    echo get_details($l)."\n";
            }

        }
        // Remove an item from the array after we have crawled it.
        // This prevents infinitely crawling the same page.
        array_shift($crawling);
        // Follow each link in the crawling array.
        foreach ($crawling as $site) {
            follow_links($site);
        }

    }
    // Begin the crawling process by crawling the starting link first.
    follow_links($start);

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```